# Why does QFontMetrics::maxWidth return such a large value?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

Windows 7 SP1
MSVS 2010
Qt 4.8.4

I want to determine the maximum size of a QLineEdit widget knowing the maximum number of characters that must fit into it.

Therefore, I want to use:

```
int QFontMetrics::maxWidth () const
Returns the width of the widest character in the font.
```

But this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFontMetrics>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    QFontMetrics metrics(QApplication::font()); 
    cout << "Default -     Max width: " << metrics.maxWidth() << " Width of X: " << metrics.width('X') << endl;
    const QFont f("Monospace", 8);
    QFontMetrics metrics2(f); 
    cout << "Monospace 8 - Max width: " << metrics2.maxWidth() << " Width of X: " << metrics2.width('X') << endl;
    const QFont f2("Cambria", 16);
    QFontMetrics metrics3(f2); 
    cout << "Cambria 16 -  Max width: " << metrics3.maxWidth() << " Width of X: " << metrics3.width('X') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs this:

```
Default -     Max width: 23 Width of X: 6
Monospace 8 - Max width: 23 Width of X: 6
Cambria 16 -  Max width: 91 Width of X: 12
```

Question: Why is the maximum width so much larger than the width of 'X'? Is there some super large character in the font that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Qt issue, as the underlying Windows APIs (`GetTextMetrics` and `GetTextExtentPoint`) give the same values.

Don't forget that a font may include many glyphs for unusual characters:  ligatures, various long dashes, symbols, dingbats, and characters from alphabets you weren't expecting.

I'm mildly surprised this happens for the "monospace" font, but apparently, those are only fixed pitch for the subset of characters the font was designed for.  Courier New, for example has a few dozen characters that are more than twice the width of the average character, such as U+0713 SYRIAC LETTER GAMAL: ܓ.

If being right most of the time is sufficient, I'd take the average character width, round it up a bit, and multiply it out.  If the user needs to enter several unusually wide characters, you might need to scroll a little, but that's not the end of the world.

If you know it's always going to be English, you may as well measure a capital W and use that.

Comment: That is exactly my concern -- I'm writing an application that must have international support. Depending on whether the font supports 'W' is too English/ASCII-centric. So, I'll keep thinking; possibly writing my own MaxWidth and determining what are the characters that cause this. Interesting: this [link](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13399) report doesn't have the same problem. It outputs expected values for `QFontMetrics::maxWidth`. But he is using Debian 6 and perhaps I need to drill down into GetTextMetrics, as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also looking forward to find which Cambria glyph is 8 times the size of 'W'.

Comment: If you're trying to be 100% correct for all languages and fonts, then it's too simplistic to multiply out the max character width by the maximum number of characters.  Characters can combine in surprising ways into grapheme clusters.  Most of the ones I can think of offhand would probably be narrower than the individual characters that comprise them, but I wouldn't be surprised if some are wider than the constituent characters.  Who knows what sorts of kerning hints might come into play as well.